# Why Qtip2 goes off screen while zooming on a mobile device?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip2

Hello i have a problem with Qtip2 and i can't understand why is not working. If you access this fiddle with a tablet or mobile device:

https://jsfiddle.net/number23/g1oxnjbp/

You can notice that if click on a structure and you zoom, the tooltip remain in position.

While at this address (my game) with the same html, the tooltip goes offscreen.

1) http://dev1.medieval-europe.eu

2) user: test password: b86a6

3) go to http://dev1.medieval-europe.eu/index.php/region/view

4) Click on a structure and then zoom.

I tried everything and i am lost... why it behaves differently?

**Html**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="wrapper">
<div class='list-structures'>
  <div class='structure' id="structure1">
    <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/snveiircj/academy_1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class='structure' id="structure2">
    <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/snveiircj/academy_1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class='list-structures'>
  <div class='structure' id="structure3">
    <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/snveiircj/academy_1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class='structure' id="structure4">
    <img src="https://s19.postimg.org/snveiircj/academy_1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Jscript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.structure').each(function() {
    $(this).qtip({
      content: "<p><a href='#'> clickme</a> MehMehMehMehMehMeh<br/><br/><br/>hMEhMEhMEhMEhMEhMEhMEh<br/><br/></p>",
      hide: {
        fixed: true,
        delay: 100,
        event: 'mouseout',
      },
      show: 'click',
      style: 'qtip-dark',
      position: {
        my: 'top left',
        at: 'bottom right',        
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**css**

```
div.list-structures {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

div.structure {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div.structure img {
  padding: 1px;
  border: 2px solid darkgrey;
}
```